# Decrypting string messages in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Does anybody know of any NPM library which can do this? I tried CryptoJS but it doesn't work. The error in browser console is `Cannot read property 'encrypt' of undefined` for the code `console.log(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('scrambled', 'eggs'));`. I already imported it using `import * as CryptoJS from 'cryptojs';`

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Don't assume a popular library doesn't work because you have a compilation error. It probably means *the code used* doesn't work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right. But I posted the code above. Do you find anything wrong in it?

Comment: You only posted a single line. Did you check the examples [in the library's repo](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)?  Did you notice the difference in the imports ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried importing it like `import aes from 'crypto-js/aes'` but it gives error `Error: Can't resolve 'crypto-js/aes'`. Any suggestions? I know I'm a noob, but I'm really eager and curious about this issue, in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and surfing, this is what I needed.

Java Encryption:

```
    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    final String ALGO = "AES";
    String password = "1234567890123456";
    String plain = "fskajhdfosjksaiodsajdoendklnassao";

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), ALGO);
    String keyForJS = encoder.encodeToString(password.getBytes());

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = encoder.encodeToString(encVal);
```

Angular Decryption:

```
decrypt(data: string): string {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('MTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2Nw==');
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, {
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let decryptedText = decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return decryptedText;
  }
```